# ReGex Problem get number of players

Tags: php, regex, curl, scrape

I want to scrape the the number of players from each playlist, just the value no commas.

```
NOBLE MAP PACK (652 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>
```

Above is the end of one of the list items with the "652" that's all I want.

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($c, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.bungie.net/mobile/playlists.aspx',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    ));
$r = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

preg_match_all('|([\w\s]+)</a> </h4>\s*([0-9,]+) Players|s', $r, $m);
```

This is the source code from http://www.bungie.net/mobile/playlists.aspx you can't view it unless you use a moblie phone emulator or look at source.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>

</title>
</head>
<body>
<!--
<div id="page">

    <span id="pageClass"></span>
    <div id="mainContent">
        <table class="breadcrumb" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="/mobile/reachonline.aspx" id="reachBackLink" class="ajax">Back</a></td>
                <td class="middle"><h3>Playlists</h3></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>



        <ul id="arrowList">
                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=29898" id="playLink_0" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">NOBLE MAP PACK (652 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=30228" id="playLink_1" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">COMMUNITY SLAYER </span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=30353" id="playLink_2" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">GRIFBALL </span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=30446" id="playLink_3" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">FIREFIGHT LIMITED </span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=30291" id="playLink_4" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">FIREFIGHT ARCADE </span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=25886" id="playLink_5" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">RUMBLE PIT (2,997 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=29220" id="playLink_6" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">LIVING DEAD (3,360 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=25885" id="playLink_7" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">TEAM SLAYER (8,167 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=29978" id="playLink_8" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">MLG (719 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=28808" id="playLink_9" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">TEAM SWAT (5,936 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=29219" id="playLink_10" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">TEAM SNIPERS (1,616 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=28474" id="playLink_11" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">TEAM OBJECTIVE (668 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=28475" id="playLink_12" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">MULTI TEAM (1,304 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=28476" id="playLink_13" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">BIG TEAM BATTLE (3,625 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=28477" id="playLink_14" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">INVASION (1,320 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=28478" id="playLink_15" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">FIREFIGHT (1,673 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=28479" id="playLink_16" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">SCORE ATTACK (429 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=28779" id="playLink_17" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">CO-OP CAMPAIGN (199 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=28481" id="playLink_18" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">TEAM ARENA (630 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=28480" id="playLink_19" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">DOUBLES ARENA (807 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="/mobile/playlist.aspx?cid=30227" id="playLink_20" class="bothSides ajax"><span class="bothSidesLeft">FFA ARENA (112 Players)</span><span>&#160;</span></a></li>
                </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">

        <p>&copy; 2011 Bungie, Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
        <ul class="nav_footer">
            <li class="left"><a id="mLink" href="/mobile/dl/">mobile</a></li>
            <li class="center">&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="right"><a id="fsLink" href="/mobile/redirect.aspx?path=%2fstats%2freach%2fplaylists.aspx">full site</a></li>         
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
<a[^>]*?id=\"playLink[^>]*?>.*? \(([0-9,]+) Players\)
```

Remove commas afterwards using strreplace.